# Search/autocomplete with Elasticsearch/Searchkick used to work but now broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a Rails 4.0.2 app which runs search/autocomplete on `acts_as_taggable_on` tag objects.  I've done the necessary code injection to make these tags searchable, and the searching worked for a while.  Recently I've been monkeying around with some server config and now this search no longer works on production.  It still works in development, and in fact it also works in the production console.

```
RAILS_ENV=production RACK_ENV=production rails c
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.reindex
```

does not solve the problem, nor does doing it from rake via

```
RAILS_ENV=production RACK_ENV=production rake searchkick:reindex:all
```

when I try to access the HTTP request for my autocomplete, I get a Status 500 Internal Server Error.  The error log reads

```
Tire::Search::SearchRequestFailed (400 : {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[pv808XIxTTizZzRjhply7Q][acts_as_taggable_on_tags_production][4]: 
SearchParseException[[acts_as_taggable_on_tags_production][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"multi_match\":{\"fields\":[\"name.autocomplete\"],\"query\":\"test\",\"analyzer\":\"searchkick_autocomplete_search\"}},\"size\":10,\"from\":0,\"fields\":[]}]]]; nested:
QueryParsingException[[acts_as_taggable_on_tags_production] [multi_match] analyzer [searchkick_autocomplete_search] not found]; }{[pv808XIxTTizZzRjhply7Q][acts_as_taggable_on_tags_production][3]: 
SearchParseException[[acts_as_taggable_on_tags_production][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"multi_match\":{\"fields\":[\"name.autocomplete\"],\"query\":\"test\",\"analyzer\":\"searchkick_autocomplete_search\"}},\"size\":10,\"from\":0,\"fields\":[]}]]]; nested:
QueryParsingException[[acts_as_taggable_on_tags_production] [multi_match] analyzer [searchkick_autocomplete_search] not found]; }{[pv808XIxTTizZzRjhply7Q][acts_as_taggable_on_tags_production][2]: 
SearchParseException[[acts_as_taggable_on_tags_production][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"multi_match\":{\"fields\":[\"name.autocomplete\"],\"query\":\"test\",\"analyzer\":\"searchkick_autocomplete_search\"}},\"size\":10,\"from\":0,\"fields\":[]}]]]; nested: 
QueryParsingException[[acts_as_taggable_on_tags_production] [multi_match] analyzer [searchkick_autocomplete_search] not found]; }{[pv808XIxTTizZzRjhply7Q][acts_as_taggable_on_tags_production][1]: 
SearchParseException[[acts_as_taggable_on_tags_production][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"multi_match\":{\"fields\":[\"name.autocomplete\"],\"query\":\"test\",\"analyzer\":\"searchkick_autocomplete_search\"}},\"size\":10,\"from\":0,\"fields\":[]}]]]; nested: 
QueryParsingException[[acts_as_taggable_on_tags_production] [multi_match] analyzer [searchkick_autocomplete_search] not found]; }{[pv808XIxTTizZzRjhply7Q][acts_as_taggable_on_tags_production][0]: 
SearchParseException[[acts_as_taggable_on_tags_production][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"multi_match\":{\"fields\":[\"name.autocomplete\"],\"query\":\"test\",\"analyzer\":\"searchkick_autocomplete_search\"}},\"size\":10,\"from\":0,\"fields\":[]}]]]; nested: 
QueryParsingException[[acts_as_taggable_on_tags_production] [multi_match] analyzer [searchkick_autocomplete_search] not found]; }]","status":400}):
```

I've tried everything I know how to do, including restarting elasticsearch, reindexing, reindex all, deleting the index and reindexing, and nothing seems to work, and now I am at a loss.  Am I missing something obvious or does anyone see what can be wrong?  The biggest mystery is that this all used to work on production until recently, and I haven't changed any of the code!

EDIT: If it helps, I'm also doing search/autocomplete for my `User` records, but those still work fine on production...

Answer (score 0):

I also get this type of error for this I have reinstall elasticsearch please try this